# How to merge typescript module defintions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a JavaScript module that has a custom `.d.ts` file. Lets call the module `Foobar`:

*foobar.js*

```js
function foobar (opts) {
  this.register = plugin => {
    plugin(this)
  }

  this.decorate = (prop, value) => {
    this[prop] = value
  }

  return this
}
export default foobar
```

*foobar.d.ts*

```js
export interface FoobarPlugin {
  (inst: FoobarInst): void
}

export interface FoobarInst {
  register(plugin: FoobarPlugin): void
  decorate(prop: string, value: any): void
}

export default function foobar (): FoobarInst
```

I also have plugin:

*fuzzbuzz.js*

```js
function fuzzbuzz (inst) {
  inst.decorate('fuzzbuzz', true)
}

export default fuzzbuzz
```

*fuzzbuzz.d.ts*

```js
import { FoobarInst } from '../foobar/foobar'

export default function fuzzbuzz (inst: FoobarInst): void
```

I load the plugin into my module:

*index.ts*

```js
import foobar from './foobar/foobar'
import fuzzbuzz from './fuzzbuzz/fuzzbuzz'

const inst = foobar()

inst.register(fuzzbuzz)

inst.fuzzbuzz // -> true
```

**What do I need to add to fuzzbuzz.d.ts in order to update the FoobarInst type definition?**

I have tried variations of:

```js
declare module foobar {
  interface FoobarInst {
    fuzzbuzz: boolean
  }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  }
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: How is register defined? Does it propage the new extended type? If it does only runtime changes the type system cannot spot that.

Comment: Its a JavaScript module so it does not matter what register does. Just know that it would modify the foobar function prototype

Comment: So you basically want type merging on classes. They are not allowed this way, but you can get something similar with mixins.

Comment: Nope I just want to merge the function options object interfaces

Comment: Again - if the type difference depends on whether `register` was executed, then it also has to deal with the type changes. Otherwise the type system will be broken before (if "statically" added, it seems you are looking for this) or afterwards (no update at all).

Comment: I see what you mean. Can I define the definition for register in such a way that would allow it to generically modify the foobar type? Also, I'm going to expand my example to actually implement register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @ford04 for a great reply. With the links provided I was able to solve my specific goal.

The important detail with my scenario is both `foobar` and `fuzzbuzz` are authored in JavaScript, and have custom `.d.ts` definition files. Additionally, the `foobar` module does not use `declare module` but instead an `export default` on the singular function the module natively exports.

The solution code is:

```
| - node_modules \
|   - foobar \
|     - foobar.js
|     - foobar.d.ts
|     - package.json
|   - fuzzbuzz \
|     - fuzzbuzz.js
|     - fuzzbuzz.d.ts
|     - package.json
| - index.ts
| - package.json
```

*foobar.js*

```js
function foobar (opts) {
  this.register = plugin => {
    plugin(this)
  }

  this.decorate = (prop, value) => {
    this[prop] = value
  }

  return this
}

export default foobar
```

*foobar.d.ts*

```js
export interface FoobarPlugin {
  (inst: FoobarInst): void
}

export interface FoobarInst {
  register(plugin: FoobarPlugin): void
  decorate(prop: string, value: any): void
}

export default function foobar (): FoobarInst
```

*foobar/package.json*

```
{  
  "main": "foobar.js",
  "types": "foobar.d.ts",
}
```

*fuzzbuzz.js*

```js
function fuzzbuzz (inst) {
  inst.decorate('fuzzbuzz', true)
}

export default fuzzbuzz
```

*fuzzbuzz.d.ts*

```js
import { FoobarInst } from 'foobar'

declare module "foobar" {
  interface FoobarInst {
    fuzzbuzz: boolean
  }
}

export default function fuzzbuzz (inst: FoobarInst): void
```

*fuzzbuzz/package.json*

```
{
  "main": "fuzzbuzz.js",
  "types": "fuzzbuzz.d.ts",
}
```

*index.ts*

```js
import foobar from 'foobar'
import fuzzbuzz from 'fuzzbuzz'

const inst = foobar()

inst.register(fuzzbuzz)

inst.fuzzbuzz // -> true and no type error!
```

**Important Details**

- Specify the type definitions in `package.json`
- `declare module '<library>'` will merge declarations even if the `<library>` does not use `declare module` explicitly (I believe it is still considered a module by TypeScript regardless).
- This prototype augmentation / decoration is error prone in the sense that just by importing `fuzzbuzz` into `index.ts` will cause the types to merge...even if you do not call `.register(fuzzbuzz)`. @ford04 answer provides more context on this *Therefore, it makes sense to place the type augmentation and foobar.register(fuzzbuzz) in one module, so that types and run-time code are in sync.*

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). I think, an `import` statement is missing in `fuzzbuzz.d.ts` to let TS recognize, that the given declarations extend/augment an already existing `"foobar"` module:

fuzzbuzz.d.ts:

```
import { FoobarOpts } from "foobar"; // can be any import, preferrably one of "foobar" 

declare module "foobar" {
  // your module extensions
}
```

#### Regarding plugin architecture

The plugin extensions have to be statically analyzable by the compiler. That means, you cannot make TS augment the `foobar` *as soon as* `foobar.register(fuzzbuzz)` is called or via dynamic import.

Instead, the module is seen as augmented, when `fuzzbuzz.d.ts` is included as input for the compilation either by [module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) or [automatic inclusion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details) of `.ts`/`.d.ts` files in the project directory. Therefore, it makes sense to place the type augmentation and `foobar.register(fuzzbuzz)` in one module, so that types and run-time code are in sync. A minimal example:

foobar.ts:

```
declare module "foobar" {
  // Plugin gets the options and possibly some internal "foobar" state
  type Plugin = (opts: FoobarOpts, state: {}) => void;

  interface FoobarOpts {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
  }

  export default function foobar(opts: FoobarOpts): void;

  function register(plugin: Plugin): void;
}
```

my-plugin.ts:

```
import { register, Plugin, FoobarOpts } from "foobar";

const fuzzBuzzPlugin: Plugin = (opt: FoobarOpts, state) => {
  opt.fuzzbuzz; // fuzzbuzz available now.
};

// set type augmentation...
declare module "foobar" {
  export interface FoobarOpts {
    fuzzbuzz: boolean;
  }
}

// ... and run-time plugin extension in one module, so they go hand in hand
register(fuzzBuzzPlugin);
```

client.ts:

```
import foobar from "foobar";

foobar({ bar: 42, foo: "buh", fuzzbuzz: true }); // works with fuzzbuzz
```

Comment: Great reply -- What if I'm not using `declare module` in my main foobar code? Also, I changed the code in my original question so it better reflects my actual project

Comment: @etarrowo e.g. If you have `foobar.ts` somewhere under `node_modules/foobar`, a `types` field in `package.json` pointed to it and `export` its members, it should be the same (see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules) how absolute paths are resolved).